# no data after forking a child in linux

Tags: c++, linux, process, fork

Something is in front of my eyes but I don't see it.

```
if (childpid == 0)
        {
               std::cout << "Hi" << std::endl;
               int rc = startDevice2( (char*)devices,ports);
               std::cout << rc << std::endl;

        }
        else
        {
                waitpid (-1, NULL, 0);
                std::cout << "Parent process stops" << std::endl;
        }
```

A dummy startDevice2 is the following

```
int startDevice2(char* x, int port) { return 4;}
```

So instead of seeing rc = 4 in my stdout, I don't see nothing. startDevice2 is linked from another file. !!! Hi is printed but the rc in NOT.

What is so wrong? I was expecting to see rc at the child's code

Comment: What is i? What is destinations.size()? Are you sure the first is greater than the second?

Comment: nothng special. just edited the code. I takes several values and bigger than 10.

Comment: Have you checked whether the variable `i` is really greater than or equal to `destination.size()`? Use the debugger or at least put a `cout` into the `startServer` branch, too.

Comment: If you don't see anything, you don't hit the else branch *at all*. Add some debug output before `startServer` (e.g. `cout << i << endl`).

Comment: No if else. Just straight to the code. Hi is printed by rc is not

Comment: @cateof: are you sure that `startDevice2` doesn't do anything weird (like disconnecting standard output)? `cout << i << endl` should print *something* regardless of `i`'s value.

Comment: Yeah it should at least print the newline.. Are you using that dummy `startDevice2` or using the normal one?

Comment: The child really ought to `exit` once it is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the program doesn't reach the point past `startDevice2`, either that function takes very long to complete or it crashes the program. Are you sure that the parameters given are correct? For example it's suspicious that you cast the `devices` parameter.

(Assuming the "dummy" `startDevice2` isn't the real one used)